# params does not retrieve anything passed along in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is code in index.html.erb:

```
  <%= link_to 'Back', '/url_handler?url=@return_to&index=0' %>
```

Here is the mapping for /url_handler in routes.rb:

```
  match '/url_handler', :to => 'application#url_handler'
```

Here is the code for url_handler in application controller:

```
  def url_handler
    url = params[:url]  
    index = params[:index] 

    if index == 1 then
      step_forward(url)
    elsif index == 0 then
      step_back
    end

    redirect_to url
  end

  private

  #record path to current page
  def step_forward(current_path)
    session[:page_step] += 1
    session[('page' + session[:page_step].to_s).to_sym] = current_path if session[:page_step] > 1
  end

  #return link for previous page in page step
  def step_back
    session[:page_step] -= 1
  end
```

The problem is that 2 params in url_handler does not retrieve the @return_to and 0 passed along in index.html.erb. @return_to has a valid value in it when passed along.

Any solutions for the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'Back', '/url_handler?url=@return_to&index=0' %>
```

Should be

```
<%= link_to 'Back', "/url_handler?url=#{@return_to}&index=0" %>
```

Note double quotes and return_to

Check your log file log/development.log to see what values are passed in params